# Android Applications Linking Activity

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have two different activities in my android applications. The first(MainActivity) has ImageButton through which onClick it's getting navigate two second activity(Numbers). This is my code of MainActivity

```
package com.android.learning_numbers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton imageButton;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

public void addListenerOnButton() {
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Numbers.class);
                    startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now here there is no error in error log but when application is getting launched on click of imagebutton it is getting crashed. & showing error in LogCat. What i do now. Please help..

Comment: and error seems to be in Numbers Activity... if possible, post that class also..

Comment: @Gopal Rao no Number activity is completely works fine.

Comment: @StinePike this is the message i am getting in LogCat "at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)"

Comment: Did you declare the `Numbers` Activity in your Manifest.xml

Comment: Thinks so you have not declared numbers activity in the manifest file

Comment: @Android Developer how do i declare Numbers activity in mainfest??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. in your manifest before `</application>`

```
 <activity 
        android:name="com.android.learning_numbers.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity
        android:name=".Numbers" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you haven't declared the Numbers Activity in the Android Manifest.
If an Activity is not declared in the Manifest, as far as the application is concerned, the Activity does not exist which causes the application to crash.

```
<application>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.learning_numbers.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.learning_numbers.Numbers"/>
</application>
```

Comment: i have done this <activity
            android:name="com.android.learning_numbers.MainActivity"></activity>

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:name="com.android.learning_numbers.Numbers"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
```

Comment: then it is launching number acitivity as defualt. i want mainacitivity as my default